# load local infile query run successful but data is not getting uploaded in server table Mysql 8.0

Tags: mysql, odbc, mysql-odbc-connector

I am using mysql 8.0 at server machine and mysql 5.5 at client machine, but when i am trying load local infile query from client machine the query is getting executed successfully but data is not getting uploaded into the server database

but when i am trying to execute the same query on client machine using sqlyog and connecting to Server machine mysql the query is getting executed successful and data is getting uploaded on the server side.

My client machine application uses mysql ODBC driver to communicate with Server machine mysql.

Any suggestion why i am getting this kind of issue.

Comment: When you use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` then the **shared** remote file to be loaded must be accessible from the local system using its UNC filename (like `\\server\share\folder\filename`) under the local account which is used for running local MySQL service.

Comment: Hi Akina, thank you for your reply you mean to say i have to pass the file path in this format \\111.11.11.11\newfile\file2\new.txt. when the query is getting executed through application over odbc driver please correct if i am wrong

Comment: ODBC driver has nothing to do with it at all. When you ask MySQL to execute `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` and give UNC as a parameter, MySQL asks its local OS's file requestor to copy this remote file to local filesystem (think that it asks to perform `copy remote_unc local_temp_filename`), requestor copies and returns the filepath to maked local copy of this file, then MySQL executes `LOAD DATA INFILE` using returned filepath as data source. ODBC is not used in this process. PS. I am not sure does some temporary filename or original filename is used for local file copy - you may test.

Comment: i Have just changed my ODBC driver and know i am getting this error in my odbc log file Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides;  even do i have added local_infile=1 on client and server machine.

Comment: This may be, for example, filesystem access rights issue... anycase this is another problem which is not related to initial problem and must be solved separately.

Comment: I cannot pass the filename in UNC because i am running my command from the same machine where i have placed my file and from that machine i am trying to access mysql which is installed on different machine

Comment: You MUST use UNC. You read my words inattentively. This UNC must be UNC for remote server (where loading command is executed), not for local station (where the command to load is sent from). Looking from the MySQL server your workstation is remote node where the file to be loaded is posessed, and this file is (must be) accessible from MySQL server's OS using some UNC.

Comment: Example. Workstation is 1.1.1.1, server is 2.2.2.2, the file `file.csv` to be loaded is posessed on the workstation in a folder `folder1\folder2`, and `folder1` is shared as `f1`. Then the command (slashes are non-quoted specially) will be `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '\\1.1.1.1\f1\folder2\file.csv' ...`.

Comment: But when I am running the same command from sqlyog it is getting executed at that time I am not providing UNC from workstation

Comment: I do not know what sqlyog is and respectively what it do in practice - maybe it pre-processes your query and makes proper additions/convertions, or performs hidden file copying... or maybe it is client-server complex at all...